# Emulator: glClear:466 GL err 0x506

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator

My android studio emulator crashes anytime I run a project and Event Log has this error (Emulator: glClear:466 GL err 0x506) repeating about a hundred times. I've updated my studio, created and tried various AVDs (API 27 and 26).

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, 
Set this in your Virtual Devices in Android Studio
"Emulated Performance - Graphics" -> Software - GLES 2.0